# How to switch peripherals from desktop and notebook?

Tags: laptop, desktop, switch, kvm

I’m about to have a laptop computer and I’m trying to decide the best way to switch my peripherals from it to my desktop computer and back. The plan is to have the desktop as a gaming station with Windows and to use my laptop to work with Linux, being able to switch all my stuff eg.: monitors, keyboard, mouse, headphone etc.

Here is a poorly made draw of what the setup may look like:
[image]

I know there’s KVM switches, but none of them seems to be with HDMI or practical enough to meet those requirements.

If it’s worth to mention, the laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad Carbon X1 6th gen.

Also, I’m using two monitors, one of them in vertical. I’m planning to use this vertical one as a fix monitor to the laptop, but I would like to be able to change it later if possible.

Comment: What kind of laptop are you using? There might be a solution provided by the manufacturer.